# Mouse doesn't go left side monitor only goes Right side

Tags: 18.04, mouse, settings, cursor, external-monitor

So I have 2 external monitor, so my mouse cursor only goes the right side monitor, can not take mouse to left side, can't find any options to fix it, any suggestions how to control or move mouse both sides right or left from laptop.

Comment: Are you sure that the display on the left is actually oriented to the left in terms of how your displays are configured?

Comment: Can you use your mouse cursor both left and right side external monitors? I can not see any config actually

Comment: System Settings > Displays?

Comment: I can not find such settings on Ubuntu

Comment: Well it's there!  So keep looking...  Type "Settings" and there is a category "Displays" on the left side. You should be able to see a graphical representation of your displays so that you can click and drag them into place. Your operating system and displays have no capability to know the physical location of the displays in relation to each other.  You have to set that up in system settings. I don't know how to describe it any easier than to use the "Displays" tab in the "Settings" application. Before you respond, make sure that you have exhaustively gone thru these settings

Comment: Are you sure that you're using Ubuntu?  Which version and flavor?

Comment: It's 18.04, problem is mouse cursor is not going left side external monitor, all the time I need move from right side. I did check but didn't see any options that can allow me to move it in both sides to use my external monitor, it just work only from right side:)

Comment: Once you navigate to Settings > Displays, all you have to do is drag and drop your displays to match their physical orientation